# UIScrollView layout not correct in IB

Tags: ios

I set zero top space for dark blue view to scrollview in IB, but doesn't correct in runtime. CarEditorCell just a subclass from UIView have a border.

[image: pic]

Comment: Do all other views have correct constraints? Perhaps it's best to also show the list of constraints for this viewcontroller.

Comment: If you are in XCode 6, check that you are disabling the "Constraint to margins" ckeckbox : http://i.stack.imgur.com/xUZG4.png

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear..anyway if you are placing a uiview on scrollview,then do this.

first place a scrollview and set the constraints(leading,trailing and top space).
then place your view on scrollview.set same constraints for this view also.and set two constraints extra ie;(x center alignment and y center alignment).
 be sure that not to set any width and height for any view.
dont forget to set x and y center alignments to your view and uncheck "constrain to margins".

hope it helps.